# How can i rename Array to API Name in IDAPro?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, decompiler

I am studying to analysis malware..

While to analysis a malware using IDA, I want to rename array to API Name.

To Help your understanding, attached image.
[image]

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to structure, this will produce much more readable code.

In order to do this you have to do the following:

1. Create a structure in structures window, according to the size of array, create there corresponding number of fields (Open window, press <kbd>INS</kbd>, use <kbd>d</kbd> key to add fields).
2. Rename structure fields according to API names, and set their type as function pointers with <kbd>Y</kbd> key. For example for `GetProcAddress` field it will look like `_DWORD (__stdcall *pGetProcAddress)(_DWORD, _DWORD);` - it is a standard definition of [C function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) with small addition of `__stdcall` marker of the calling convention.
3. Set your a1 variable type to the created structure (In decompiler window locate cursor on your `a1` variable, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and enter the structure name)

Let me know if you need more detailed walkthrough.

As an alternative for defining structure inside IDA (bullets 1 and 2) you can write a header file with something similar to the following (btw, see the type definitions in the structure):

```
struct apis
{
  void* (__stdcall *pGetProcAddress)(_DWORD, _DWORD);
  _DWORD (__stdcall *pSetErrorMode)(_DWORD);
  _DWORD (__stdcall *pGetTempPathA)(_DWORD, _DWORD);
  _DWORD (__stdcall *pGetTempGileNameA)(_DWORD *, _DWORD *, _DWORD, _DWORD *);
};
```

and import it into the IDB with <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd>. You can find and edit this structure in Local types window (<kbd>Shift+F1</kbd>).

Comment: I completed step1, But I can't set their type as function pointers.. Press Y and then I don't know What I input.. in box[Please enter a string]. thank you sir.

Comment: Answer updated. Do you have definitions of HMODULE and LPCSTR types in your IDB ?

Comment: No, I don't have HMODULE and LPCSTR..

Comment: So use _DWORD as a parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much!and, I setted Function Pointer,, and then I will set a1,,I know to set structure using Alt+Q, but you said Y! then What I input there?

Comment: In the bullet 3 you enter there the name of structure you created previously. BTW, answer updated again.

Comment: Okay Thank you sir, although I can't succeed it yet..I will be success after studying it.